# Trying to compare a value between two data sets in Tableau but its not displaying correct details

Tags: tableau-api, datasource, tableau-desktop, kpi

I'm relatively new to Tableau and I have 2 data sets, one from 2016 olympics and one from 2020 olympics.

I want to compare the results from 2016s "Total" amount of medals for each country against the 2020 olympics "Total" amount of medals achieved by each country.

This is assigned by the "Total" value within my data set as shown in the screenshot
[image: Olympics 2020]
[image: Olympics 2016]

In Tableau when I create a sheet and input the "Names" and "Total" medal count, it displays the information correctly for the 2016 data with the Total amount of medals achieved by each country.

Although, when I try to include 2020s Olympic data to compare against, it displays the wrong number as it should be displaying "24" for Canada but displays as 1.

Not sure if I should be including any extra fields onto this sheet which is why I am here to ask, is there another way I could do this to where I can get the correct results displayed back to me?

[image]
[image: Wrong information displayed]

Comment: There are different ways to combine data from multiple tables. The best way depends on the circumstances. I recommend reading about Union and Blending in the Tableau online help to see two features that might help in your case. Start simple to see how these features work before going to far down one path.

Comment: It seems like Union would be the preferred way for me as my data is not large and it's supported. They're relatively the same data on both data sets, I just don't understand why when I add the "Total" from the 2020 set into Tableau, it displays the wrong information. Do you know if i'm putting "Total" in the right place from the screenshots sent?

Comment: It doesn't look like you specified a Union in the data source page, it looks like you specified a relationship between the Medals table and the "Rio 2016 Medals" table. I suggest making a data source that only has the union of the two -- even better, first rename the tabs in Excel to be 2020 and 2016. Then realize SUM([Total]) will be the sum of both years, but you'll notice Tableau will generate a field with the table name that you can use to distinguish between Years. You might want to change the name and type of that field for convenience.